# What rendering engine does Visual Studio use for HTML?

Tags: visual-studio-2005

Does anyone know what rendering engine Visual Studio uses for rendering it's HTML previews??

It seems to be kinder to IE6 but still not really WYSIWYG

Comment: Must confess to often having wondered about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to whatever renders the page while you're editing it, most likely something they wrote specifically for that purpose since it needs to allow you to edit the content.